Delete row from CSV after the request is processed in Jmeter
I have a CSV file that contains 500 records. Each of my runs will consume 50 records, and the run will continue for 10 hours with a 1 hour time delay between the runs. To have distinct records for each run, I want to delete the records once the request is executed.

You could go for i.e. JSR223 Sampler in tearDown Thread Group to remove first 50 lines after the test run, the relevant Groovy code would be something like:
def csvFile = new File('test.csv')
def originalContent = csvFile.readLines()
def newContent = originalContent.drop(50).join('\n')
csvFile.write(newContent)

The code will remove first 50 lines from the original file and write the remaining lines back.

I tried the repro but am getting the below error. Let me know if anything is missing.
JSR233 Sampler:
def csvFile = new File('OrderNo.csv')
def originalContent = csvFile.readLines()
def newContent = originalContent.drop(3).join('\n')
csvFile.write(newContent)
Sampler Result:
:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script40.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '' @ line 1, column 1.
